# Is there a Linux equivalent for the Windows InetIsOffline function?

Tags: linux, libc

Is there a Linux function that is equivalent to the [`InetIsOffline` function in Windows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776460.aspx) (provided by `url.dll`) that can tell me whether the system is connected to the Internet, or do I have to cook up something myself?

The reason I ask is that I am an early-adopter of [Lhogho](http://lhogho.sourceforge.net/). I found out how to do this in [Windows](http://codeaholic.blogspot.com/2011/12/lhogho-isinetoffline-example-of-win32.html) and wanted to develop something to offer the same functionality in Linux.

Comment: f the workstation has knowledge of the state of the device that connects to "the internet". These days, this is less and less the case, as modems/routers take over the role of the “endpoint” (DHCP client, PPPOE client, etc., so as to allow multiple devices), rather than your own workstation as it often used to during the modem days.

Comment: What an absurd function that is (and also very strangely named)... You should not check whether you are connected to the internet (which, in fact, is not possible to decide in a reliable way) but if the resource you are going to access is accessible and implement proper error handling. If you only want to check if *some* site is accessible, than you should check that instead.

Comment: @Niklas: yes, it is absurd. Welcome to Windows. ;)

Comment: @boost: That's a good one, and wise as well :P Still, why do they call it `InetIsOffline` and write about it: "Determines whether the system is connected to the Internet." Wouldn't `InetIsOnline` then be much more sensible? oO

Comment: Sometimes I really ask myself what they were smoking when they designed their API. Other possible explanation: extensive utilization of Ballmer's peak.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can talk to Network Manager over D-Bus to see if anything is connected, but other than that there's no specific way of doing so. And even NM isn't always accurate.

Answer (score 1):

You could also parse some file under `/proc/net/` such as `/proc/net/if_inet6` or `/proc/net/tcp`

But why do you want to do that? If you want to check that some site is accessible, just access it programmatically (e.g. with [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/)).

And it does happen that some sites are inaccessible and others still work.

Answer (score 0):

It might mean "do I have a default route?", or at least that would be a reasonable implementation, IMHO. So, just check the routing table (`/proc/net/route`) for it :).

That of course will not work with IPv6 (you would need to parse `ipv6_route`), but it's complicated to decide how that should be treated. Maybe Wine source code, or MSDN documentation can shed light on the matter.